# How to register any user with 1 month plan?

Tags: php, registration, trial

I want to add any user in a database only for 30 days trial plan. I have no idea how to server check status of user and disable if his plan is expires.

I need to know how to add time at register time. I also want a reminder email to every user if they are near to plan expiration

anybody please

Thank You

Comment: You need to add a cron job for reminders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

m looking for WordPress  code and found daily , hourly function provided by wordpress

```
 register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'prefix_activation' );

    function prefix_activation() {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'prefix_hourly_event_hook' );
    }

    add_action( 'prefix_hourly_event_hook', 'prefix_do_this_hourly' );

    function prefix_do_this_hourly() {
        // do something every hour
    }
```

> this is working for me ...

Answer (score 1):

- Add a column `trial_end_date` in your `registration` table
- when user registers, update `trial_end_date` column with `sysdate + 30` ( *check for proper mysql syntax, this would work in `oracle`* )
- when ever user wants to use the product/plan/site, check `sysdate` with `trial_end_date`
- if values above are same, alert `trial expired` and `exit` else `continue`

Answer (score 0):

To automatically send mails to your users, you need to setup a daily CRON job that check each user's trial expiration date and sends them a mail if the expiration is near.

This is the most common way to regularly perform a task with a PHP server.

Answer (score 0):

Let this be your user_table

```
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| user_id |  name  |  date_of_register  | register_timestamp  |  member_active  |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

When someone is registerting add :

```
date_of_regsiter = date('YYYY-mm-dd'); 
// i save dates as varchar in 2014-06-20 format//
```

and `register_timestamp = time();`   (w.r.t. PHP)

now you can run a cron job from server which will detect this

it will run a script with this concept

```
$current_date = date('YYYY-mm-dd');


$user_list = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user_table")->result_array();
//codeigniter mode of fetching data from database.


foreach($user_list as $ul)
   {
      $start = strtotime($current_date);
      $end = strtotime($ul['dateof_register']);
      $days = $end - $start;
      $days = ceil($days/86400);
      if($days > 30)
        {
           //update the row where user_id = $ul['user_id'] SET member_status = 0//
           //  send email to users
        }

   }
```

Comment: Actulay i was looking for wordpress code ... i have found  hint from your answer thank you ...:) 

Jai Hind Jai Bharat

Comment: Jai Hind. Jai Hindi, Jai Bharat